# Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : error in evaluating the argument 'table' in selecting a method for function 'match'

Tags: r, error-handling, package

I am getting this error while running the LFQ workflow of DEP package. The code is as follows:

```
library(DEP)
data_results <- LFQ(comparison_table, expdesign, type = "all", control = NULL, test = NULL,
                    name = "description", ids = "Protein.IDs", alpha = 0.05, lfc = 1)
# Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
#   error in evaluating the argument 'table' in selecting a method for function 'match': 'words' should contain more than one element
```

Here's LFQ arguments:

proteins
Data.frame, The data object.

expdesign
Data.frame, The experimental design object.

fun
"man", "bpca", "knn", "QRILC", "MLE", "MinDet", "MinProb", "min", "zero", "mixed" or "nbavg", Function used for data imputation based on manual_impute and impute.

type
'all', 'control' or 'manual', The type of contrasts that will be generated.

control
Character(1), The sample name to which the contrasts are generated (the control sample would be most appropriate).

test
Character, The contrasts that will be tested if type = "manual". These should be formatted as "SampleA_vs_SampleB" or c("SampleA_vs_SampleC", "SampleB_vs_SampleC").

filter
Character, Name(s) of the column(s) to be filtered on.

name
Character(1), Name of the column representing gene names.

ids
'Character(1), Name of the column representing protein IDs.

alpha
Numeric(1), sets the false discovery rate threshold.

lfc
Numeric(1), sets the log fold change threshold.

Here's my dataset "comparison-table"

```
'data.frame':   4251 obs. of  44 variables:
 $ description          : chr  "1433B" "1433E" "1433F" "1433G" ...
 $ S2.50                : num  0.1241 0.1535 0.0477 0.0412 0.041 ...
 $ S3.50                : num  0.1649 0.2283 0.0681 0.0821 0.0925 ...
 $ S4.50                : num  0.14 0.1455 0.0323 0.0501 0.0285 ...
 $ S5.50                : num  0.1028 0.1735 0.044 0.0366 0.1784 ...
 $ S6.50                : num  0.106 0.1268 0.0424 0.038 0.0463 ...
 $ S7.50                : num  0.0578 0.0906 0 0.0503 0.043 ...
 $ S8.50                : num  0.1112 0.1262 0.0229 0.0456 0.0713 ...
 $ S9.30                : num  0.275 0.1972 0.0494 0.0632 0.1748 ...
 $ S10.50               : num  0.2444 0.1801 0.04 0.0531 0 ...
 $ S11.30               : num  0.0911 0.1381 0.0195 0.0324 0 ...
 $ S13.50               : num  0.0557 0.1223 0.0186 0.0339 0.0706 ...
 $ S16.50               : num  0.1488 0.2271 0.0692 0.1448 0.0275 ...
 $ S18.50               : num  0.133 0.1941 0.0357 0.0582 0.2929 ...
 $ S21.50               : num  0.0452 0.1454 0.0264 0.0263 0.1271 ...
 $ S22.50               : num  0.1013 0.1303 0.0439 0.0471 0.0603 ...
 $ S23.50               : num  0.1362 0.2774 0.0492 0.0716 0.0826 ...
 $ S24.30               : num  0.0806 0.105 0.0242 0.0602 0.172 ...
 $ S25.50               : num  0.2112 0.1573 0.0482 0.107 0.0221 ...
 $ S26.50               : num  0.0747 0.1473 0.026 0.0453 0.0999 ...
 $ S27.50               : num  0.1742 0.1427 0.0394 0.0982 0 ...
 $ S28.50               : num  0.1813 0.1007 0.0275 0.0493 0.0763 ...
 $ S29.50               : num  0.137 0.2102 0.0156 0.0403 0.0432 ...
 $ S31.50               : num  0.1186 0.1456 0.0539 0.1181 0.1497 ...
 $ S33.30               : num  0.1494 0.2145 0.0382 0.0588 0.1861 ...
 $ S34.50               : num  0.1192 0.1255 0.0145 0.0648 0.2043 ...
 $ S35.30               : num  0.3148 0.0675 0.1399 0.0871 0.1041 ...
 $ S36.50               : num  0.0631 0.0468 0.0097 0.0483 0.0337 ...
 $ S37.50               : num  0.1911 0.1843 0.0303 0.0876 0.0181 ...
 $ S38.30               : num  0.1872 0.1354 0.0351 0.0505 0.1045 ...
 $ S40.50               : num  0.18 0.2015 0.0771 0.0832 0.1211 ...
 $ S41.50               : num  0.1595 0.1871 0.0156 0.0717 0.0807 ...
 $ S42.30               : num  0.0743 0.1569 0.0418 0.0416 0.0323 ...
 $ S44.50               : num  0.0888 0.156 0.0571 0.0663 0 ...
 $ S45.50               : num  0.117 0.1437 0.0355 0.0283 0.0176 ...
 $ S46.50               : num  0.2356 0.1623 0.0294 0.0461 0 ...
 $ S48.50               : num  0.0876 0.1655 0.0245 0.0837 0 ...
 $ S49.50               : num  0.1308 0.1452 0.0425 0.0358 0 ...
 $ S50.50               : num  0.1036 0.1766 0.0449 0.0447 0.1131 ...
 $ S51.50               : num  0.2043 0.1906 0.0201 0.0767 0.0565 ...
 $ S52.50               : num  0.2043 0.1183 0 0.0661 0 ...
 $ Protein.IDs          : chr  "PRO_1" "PRO_2" "PRO_3" "PRO_4" ...
 $ Reverse              : chr  "" "" "" "" ...
 $ Potential.contaminant: chr  "" "" "" "" ...
```

I think this is happening because of the filter argument, not finding reverse and potential.contaminant in the protein description column but I'm not sure.

Is there a way to switch off this argument since I don't need it?

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Welcome to SO. You maximize your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)] may help. the way you provided you dataset is not reproducible

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).